# Add new column to view

Tags: sqlite, view

How can I add a new column to a view which is not defined in a table?
I would like to show a `varchar` in a new column if a certain condition is met.
The view looks like this:

```
CREATE VIEW view1 AS SELECT column1, column2 FROM table1;
```

Table1 has only the attributes column1 and column2.

I am trying to add a new column which should act like this: if column1='x' column3='test' and if column2!='x' column3='a'.

Comment: Does `SQLite` support `CASE Statements`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE` to generate the results as per the required condition in a new column

```
create view view1 as
select column1, column2,
    case when column1 = 'x' then 'test'
        when column2 != 'x' then 'a'
    end as column3
from table1;
```

Comment: I guess it does. :-) I learned something new... I can go home now.